# css to force flex list to wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

I have an ordered list with css (both of which come from elsewhere and can only be adjusted a bit) that formats the items into a row, I want to have multiple rows, but can't figure out how to force it to wrap.

I can not modify any of the "external" styles.  A [minimum viable example on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qixixozeqo/edit?html,css,output)

```css
#external1 {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.external2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 6px;
}

.external3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 6px;
}

/*this class is under my control */
.howtowrap {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
  <ol id="external1" class="external2">
    
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content 2</div>
    </li>
   <!-- I am injecting this element, I could add a class to the next li instead if that would be better -->
    <span class="howtowrap">W1</span>
    
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content 3</div>
    </li>
        <li class="external3">
      <div>content 4</div>
    </li>
    <span class="howtowrap">W2</span>
    
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content 5</div>
    </li>

    <li class="external3">
      <div>content 6</div>
    </li>
    <span class="howtowrap">W3</span>
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content 7</div>
    </li>
        <li class="external3">
      <div>content 8</div>
    </li>
    
    
  </ol>
```

I am looking for the result to look like (W1, W2 and W3 are just placeholders).  Also, I do NOT want it to wrap before the span.

```
content  content2
content3 content4
content5 content6
content7 content8
```

Comment: if you can inject elements, can't you add a new class to the ol?

Comment: @TemaniAfif: yes, I can.

Comment: I'm guessing the "external" styles are from an external stylesheet that you can't edit. However, you can include a stylesheet with the same ID and class names that would overrule and/or add to the external stylesheet declarations, as [imhvost points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77498163/21849374).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add something to the html like `<span class="howtowrap">`, you can also add a `<style>` tag, for example at the end of a list, with rules that override the current styles. Something like:

```css
#external1 {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.external2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 6px;
}

.external3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 6px;
}

/*this class is under my control */
.howtowrap {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ol id="external1" class="external2">
    
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content</div>
    </li>
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content 2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content 3</div>
    </li>
        <li class="external3">
      <div>content 4</div>
    </li>
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content 5</div>
    </li>
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content 6</div>
    </li>
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content 7</div>
    </li>
    <li class="external3">
      <div>content 8</div>
    </li>
    <!--  -->
    <style>
      #external1{
        display: inline-grid!important;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, min-content);
        grid-auto-rows: min-content;
      }
    </style>
    
  </ol>
```

Comment: Indeed. The "external" rules can't be edited but "internal" rules can be made (via `style` or another external stylesheet) to overrule or add to the "external" declarations without having to create new classes or add additional elements.

Answer (score 0):

To make the children of a flex container wrap when a number of child items fill the width of the parent, use the flex-wrap property on the parent element.

in your case:

```css
.external2 {
  /** ...old properties and values */
  flex-wrap : wrap
}
```

Comment: I can't change any of the external classes.

Comment: but I can probably add a new class to the OL or make a new class that applies to it.

Answer (score 0):

> but I can probably add a new class to the OL or make a new class that applies to it.

Ok let us add a new class `.wrappable` to the `<ol>`.

```css
/* new style rules */
.wrappable {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: wheat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrappable>li {
  flex: 1 0 calc(50% - 12px);
}


/* original untouched style rules */
#external1 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.external2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.external3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 6px;
}
```

```html
<ol id="external1" class="external2 wrappable">

  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 2</div>
  </li>

  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 4</div>
  </li>

  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 5</div>
  </li>

  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 6</div>
  </li>
  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 7</div>
  </li>
  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 8</div>
  </li>


</ol>
```

---

If you want simple wrap like text line then remove `.wrappable>li`:

```css
/* new style rules */

.wrappable {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: wheat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
}


/* original untouched style rules */

#external1 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.external2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.external3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 6px;
}
```

```html
<ol id="external1" class="external2 wrappable">

  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 2</div>
  </li>

  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 4</div>
  </li>

  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 5</div>
  </li>

  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 6</div>
  </li>
  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 7</div>
  </li>
  <li class="external3">
    <div>content 8</div>
  </li>


</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

you desired result with multiple rows, right? for that, Add a wrapper around the list items and apply the `flex-wrap` property to it. Also, you need to adjust the `flex-basis` property for `.howtowrap` elements to ensure they occupy the full width.